# List last Windows Update - vbscript

Tags: windows-update, vbscript

Im trying to write a script that reads a list of servers from a text file and outputs the last time a Windows Update was applied.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("serverlist.txt", 1)

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  'wscript.echo line
  Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", line)
  Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
  Set colHistory = objSearcher.QueryHistory(1, 1)
  For Each objEntry in colHistory
    Wscript.Echo line
    Wscript.Echo " " & objEntry.Date
  Next
Loop

file.Close
```

Im scratching my head, because I think it *should* work, but it isnt.  Here is the error im getting:

> C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\new.vbs(6, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error:
>    The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'CreateObject'

Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT:

Upon more investigating, it looks like the `Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", line)` can not be passed a variable, if I put "Servername" instead it works fine...

Comment: That seems odd. My guess is that when you read the server names from the file it's including extra characters (ie: EOL) that make it incompatible, or at least into a server name that doesn't exist. :)  Working on that idea, if you replace the `line = file.Readline` with something like `line = "ServerName"` does it work? If so then you probably need to sanitize the line read in from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head, I redid my script:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("servers.csv", 1)
server = ""

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  server = line
  'wscript.echo server
  Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", server)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo server & " Error: " & Err.Number & " Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number) & " Source: " &  Err.Source & " Description: " &  Err.Description
    WScript.Echo server & " Communications Error"
    Err.Clear
  Else
      Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
      Set colHistory = objSearcher.QueryHistory(1, 1)
      For Each objEntry in colHistory
        Wscript.Echo server & " " & objEntry.Date
      Next
  End If
Loop

file.Close
```

It *mostly* works.  It fails on machines that are off, obviously.  But it also fails on a few machines that are definitely up.  Thats a problem for a different day.